# Cannot set attributes in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export function updateAttributes(attributes: string[][], data: Object, element: HTMLElement): void {
    attributes.forEach(([attr, value]) => {
        let parsed = parseString(value, data)
        if (value !== element.attributes[attr]) {
            element.attributes[attr] = parsed
        }
    })
}
```

I have this function. I cannot set the attribute at `element.attributes[attr]`.

It says

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

I dont understand why? Cann somebody explain me why i cannot set an simple attribute?

Comment: Because Typescript. The Allow Implicit Types setting is disabled by default and will give compiler warnings/errors. indexing with `element.attributes[attr as string]` or `element.attributes[<string>attr]` should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript is correct here.

[`HTMLElement.attributes` is a `NamedNodeMap`, which is indexed by numbers like an array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) But `attr` is a clearly string here.

If you want to use this property, you need to use [the `NamedNodeMap` api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap) to get/set attributes

---

Or you can just call `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` on the element directly which works fine.

```
export function updateAttributes(attributes: string[][], data: Object, element: HTMLElement): void {
    attributes.forEach(([attr, value]) => {
        let parsed = parseString(value, data)

        // Call getAttribute and setAttribute directly on element
        if (value !== element.getAttribute(attr)) {
            element.setAttribute(attr, parsed)
        }
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.3#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwAdYBnEAZQxi1QHMAKKALnmMupoBp4AjZgeW4ArcBgCUzVlVoAoaSAAeBHDAxI0mXPmQFgUDCACCGNt2T7iDY1VPmJbWgG0Aus666MTeAOGYuICCAAtiCoGMwAEgAqALIAMgCiAcGh4vAAbjhYwPAA3tLwBfB6JmYgxAB0iMrxUGAAFnR0DsUwXGlQEMggTqLwALwAfLn5haMBqkQwpNl9hCTk9vTtnSBuelCisqOjAPQ78ADCHRDwNCAYRiX6RajZpBdWWDYIwFhwmBAAnvB48P5BIQwI228CwiHgdGWXXgAEI+rN-skMOUzg8riBLJRRL08iCQYjAeV7pdrKVMa05lMQMBNnj4ABfYEMzaM2RAA)